# Outlook forwarding rules when outlook is not running

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange-2010

Do the email forwarding rules on outlook work if the outlook itself isn't running? Are the rules server-side or client-side by default, if I'm using Exchange Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are hosted on the Exchange server, so naturally you can't access
them while in offline mode in Outlook.

If you are an admin or have access to Exchange server ,your Exchange mailbox can receive it with the server-side rules which will run even when you're offline , but if you are using Outlook to create rules,
messages/rules are only applied if you go online.

FYI for the server side filtering : [Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351134(v=exchg.160).aspx)

Comment: This is a bit confusing. So, are you saying the mail will forward when Outlook is offline, or not?

Comment: @Appleoddity  apologies for the confusion , I think I need to rephrase the answer. What I meant was that you can forward the mails when you are offline if you have configured this rule in Exchange server , as a admin. But If you have configured it from your outlook , I will not be applied until you are online. Hope this correction clears out the answer.If yes, please suggest so that I can edit the same into mail answer

Comment: @NWishAll What I wanted to know is will my rules (that I set up in outlook) still work after I turn off my PC (will emails still be forwarded). If I understand your answer correctly they will, since the rules are hosted on Exchange server. Is that correct?

Comment: @IlmarsL I am afraid no, TL;DR.. if you setup rules in Outlook, it runs only when Outlook runs...But if you want rules to run in offline mode, there is a provision provided from Exchange server side to set the rules on server, but for that you need to have access to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I note that on my version of Outlook, I can setup SOME rules to work offline. For example, moving an email to a folder, or forwarding it. But if I add a "mark as read" action, I get a popup:

"(!) This rule will only run when you check your email in Outlook. If Outlook isn't running, this rule won't work for email you check online or from another device"

The rule is then marked as "client only".

So to answer the OP's question: "it depends"

Answer (score 0):

According to the MS article below, it depends on what the rule is. For example:

- If the condition is text in the subject line, it will be client-side (and thus only run when Outlook is open
- If the condition is a recipient, the rules is server-side and therefore automatic.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/server-side-vs-client-only-rules-e1847992-8aa1-4158-8e24-ad043decf1eb